# How could Hiramekarei defeat Samehada?

Tags: boruto

Refer to episode 31, boruto.

Hiramekarei stores chakra and then release it in shapes.

Why then, Samehada don't just absorb all that chakra? How could it defeat Samehada at all?

Comment: Have the 7 swords been ranked based on the power ever? I thought it always would depend on the wielder

Comment: Which episode or chapter does this question comes from?

Comment: @絢瀬絵里 Boruto ep 31

Answer (score 2):

There is no "specific power ranking" for the seven legendary swords, and as stated in the comments, a weapon is only as powerful as its wielder. Choujiro proved this when he defeated one of "new generation -seven legendary swordsmen" with a normal sword.

Apart from the fact that it was Shizumas first time attempting to use Samehada, it is important to note that

> ***Samhehada is the only living weapon among the seven legendary swords, and as such, it has its own consciousness and personality. Therefore its actions can affect the tide of battle.*** Samehada was already absorbing all their chakra using the "bloody mist absorption technique" but that only made it want more chakra.

Samehada is actually a greedy Glutton, that loves chakra more than anything else, and it takes a large amount of will power and experience to tame it. Unfortunately for Shizuma, he could not control Samehada and so it took over his body and started going on a rampage. At that point, Shizuma was not thinking straight and he was also at a disadvantage going against two "Jonin level" kids.

The loss was not because Hiramekarei is stronger or weaker but merely due to the circumstances in which the battle took place.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the wielder. A true strength of any weapon always does.

If Boruto and Kagura had fought Kisame instead of Shizuma, they would have definitely lost.

Kisame brought out the true power of the sword that is why any chakra based attacks was useless on him and Gai needed to open the seventh gate to defeat him.

Shizuma had just got the sword and could hardly bring out it's true power.On the other hand Kagura had a better understanding because he had been training with the sword for a while now. So he brought a little bit of it's true power. Which is the reason why Shizuma lost.

The winner hear was not Hiramekarei it was Kagura and Boruto

Answer (score -2):

Who says Hiramekarei has to defeat Samehada?

The question is similar to asking how can Fire defeat Water? It cannot (under normal circumstances). Fire has an advantage against other elements which are in turn stronger than water. Similarly, Hiramekarei could be stronger than other swords, which in turn could be stronger than Samehada.